# No documentation for DEBUG flag in UrbanAirship

Tags: urbanairship.com

I noticed that there is a DEBUG flag that can be set for applications both in development and production. However the link http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#iOSGettingStarted-DebugMode
appears to be dead (or outdated?) so I have not been able to find no clear documentation on what DEBUG mode is.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is "It doesn't do anything now".

[This support document](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1358475-what-does-debug-mode-do-) says that Debug mode is going away and the functionality it used to provide is provided in other ways (although it doesn't say what that functionality was or how it's provided now).